# Autowiring required beans

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to wire beans using Annotations.. When a beans is not present in the beans.xml config file, i am getting a null pointer exception.. i expect the required=false attribute to fix this.. is that a fair expectation? If so, why is it still throwing exception even if i set required as false for that missing bean...

```
package com.rajkumar.spring;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

public class Log {

    private ConsoleWriter consoleWriter;
    private FileWriter fileWriter;


    @Autowired
    public void setConsoleWriter(ConsoleWriter consoleWriter) {
        this.consoleWriter = consoleWriter;
    }

    @Autowired(required=false)
    public void setFileWriter(FileWriter fileWriter) {
        this.fileWriter = fileWriter;
    }

    public void writeToFile(String message) {
        fileWriter.write(message); // this is throwing the error as the bean is comments in the XML file..
    }

    public void writeToConsole(String message) {
        consoleWriter.write(message);
    }


}
```

My Beans.xml is below..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd">


    <bean id="log" class="com.rajkumar.spring.Log"></bean>
    <bean id="consoleWriter"
        class="com.rajkumar.spring.ConsoleWriter">
    </bean>
    <!-- <bean id="fileWriter" class="com.rajkumar.spring.FileWriter"></bean> -->
    <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
</beans>
```

Comment: Please add the stacktrace.

Comment: Yes, Please add stacktrace. required=false just disable dependency checking.
If you would be referring `FileWriter` object later on in your code, you will get NullPointer Exception.

Comment: If a variable is `null` and you try to invoke a method on it, why are you surprised that a `NullPointerException` is thrown?

Answer (score 0):

`required=false` is to only make spring container dependency checking optional and it avoids correpsonding bean not found exception like.. *required a bean of type 'com.rajkumar.spring.FileWriter' that could not be found*.

Please note that injected object is still `null` here, hence you are seeing `NullPointerException`.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the @Component Annotation above your class definition.

```
@Component
public class Log {
...
```

Without Spring won't recognize your class to inject something somewhere and your fields will remain null. You might also want to add ComponentScan to your configuration.

Answer (score -1):

```
  public void writeToFile(String message) {
        fileWriter.write(message); // this is throwing the error as the bean is comments in the XML file..
    }
```

The error is throwing because there  is no bean injected to `fileWriter` if the bean will not be injected then try to validate if the object is not null before use it.

```
  public void writeToFile(String message) {
        if (fileWriter!=null)
        fileWriter.write(message); // this is throwing the error as the bean is comments in the XML file..
    }
```

Another approach is to use a `@PostConstruct`, for example:

```
@PostConstruct
public void initBean(){
    if (fileWriter ==null) fileWriter = new SomeFileWriter();
}
```

In that case there is no need to evaluate `fileWriter` on `writeToFile` method

Also you can use a init method instead of `@PostConstruct`

Like this:

```
  <bean id="log" class="com.rajkumar.spring.Log" init-method="myInit"></bean>
```

then on `myInit()` method try to initialize your null object.